# Parallel Algorithms for SVD

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I just have completed a preliminar theoretical study of the important SVD decomposition.
Now, I'm moving to numerical calculation of SVD.

I would like to learn directly a parallel algorithm to accomplish the task, or at least an algorithm well-suited for parallelization.

Can you tell me:
1) One (or more) of existing algorithms that match the requirement.
2) Where I can study it from (online refereces and/or books).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also worked on a CUDA implementation of parallel SVD algorithms and found this paper that helped me a lot:

[Parallel Algorithms for
the Singular Value
Decomposition](http://www.irisa.fr/sage/bernard/publis/SVD-Chapter06.pdf)

They describe SVD algorithms for both dense and sparse matrices and discuss parallelization possibilities of sparse matrices.

Comment: Thanks.. I done some googling but missed this!